# Make Highslide nonresizable and moveable from all 4 sides?

Tags: highslide

(Continuing from this: http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=24327 )

I want to make Highslide movable from all edges and nonresizable.

I have be able to make it nonresizable but I cannot get it to move from all the edges. It only moves from the top.

How would I get to do this? Ive tried the code posted in the (sadly now closed) forums but nothing.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom wrapper and add the class **.highslide-move** together with the class **.highslide-html-content**. Tie the custom wrapper to your popup using [contentId](http://highslide.com/ref/hs.contentId). See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WbDMs/ (see code from the jsFiddle below)
Note that you can’t move the popup from the outline graphic file (I’m using a black outline in my demo).

If you have a live page, I can take a look at it to see what you are missing.

**Code from the jsFiddle**
In the head section:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="highslide/highslide-with-html.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="highslide/highslide.css"/>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[ 
hs.graphicsDir = 'highslide/graphics/';
hs.outlineType = 'rounded-black';
hs.wrapperClassName = 'draggable-header';
hs.showCredits = false;
//]]>  
</script> 

<style type='text/css'>
 /* adjust the wrapper's padding */
.highslide-html-content {
  padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
}

/* for demo purposes only */
.highslide-body {
  background: yellow
}
</style>
```

In the body section 
(*replace /roadrash/7AHX9/show/light/ in the href with the page you want to open in your iframe popup*):

```
<div>
  <a href="/roadrash/7AHX9/show/light/" onclick="return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'iframe', contentId: 'highslide-html' } )">
    Content in iframe
  </a>
</div>

<div class="highslide-html-content highslide-move" id="highslide-html">
  <div class="highslide-header">
    <ul>
      <li class="highslide-close">
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="return hs.close(this)" style="cursor: pointer;"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="highslide-body"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually made a seperate page with yoru code but what it does is just simply takes me to another page; Doesnt actually show the highslide.

The page is not live.

Comment: Check that the path to your highslide-with-html.js file is correct.

Comment: Im using highslide-full.js and path is correct (for testing purposes Im using the absolute path)

Comment: Also, is there a reason the popup cant be moved from the outline graphic file?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not able to tell why your setup doesn't work without seeing your page. The popup isn't movable from the outline graphic file because we can't add the class name _.highslide-move_ to this part of the wrapper. Maybe the narrower outline graphic file `drop-shadow` will fit your need better: http://jsfiddle.net/WbDMs/1/